# The correct way to make a rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess in my site www folder that has this rewrite rule:

```
 RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /$1.php
```

It works, if you type in

```
 http://sampardee.com/urltest -
```

It finds **urltest.php** and brings it up.

However, if you type in

```
 http://sampardee.com/urltest/
```

it still brings **urltest.php** up but the CSS stops working. I have the CSS file specified in a link tag. The same results appear also when

```
 http://sampardee.com/urltest.php/
```

is accessed.

Is there any way I can fix this so that someone could type in

```
 http://sampardee.com/urltest/
```

and have **urltest.php** come up, but yet still display the linked CSS file?

Please help :)
-Sam

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with mod_rewrite, but with the css link (the browser tries to fetch http://[...]/urltest/css/default.css instead of /css/default.css).

Try adding a beginning slash, and changing the  to:

> /css/default.css

Answer (score 1):

A better idea would probably be to redirect http://sampardee.com/urltest/ to http://sampardee.com/urltest.

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/$ /$1 [R] 
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ /$1.php
```